# PGPDataFormat encryption

Tags: java, bouncycastle

When I am trying to use `pgpDataFormat` for marshaling am getting following error

> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRing found where PGPPublicKeyRing expected

Code:

```
from("endponit").process(new Processor() {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        pgpDataFormat.setKeyFileName("dharshan.pgp");
        pgpDataFormat.setPassword("123456");
        pgpDataFormat.setKeyUserid("dharshan");

    }
}).marshal(pgpDataFormat).process(new Processor() {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Complted!!!");  
    }
});
```

How to overcome?

Comment: I have solve the above problem adding   pgpDataFormat.setSignatureKeyFileName("xxxxx.pgp");.But now am getting another error as follow org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache]]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that dharshan.pgp is keyfile for private keys and you need public keys (PGPPublicKeyRing expected).